# ODE Oscillation, overdampening response

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chemistry

Below is another version of the creme brulee model. $k_{11}, k_{12},k_{21},k_{22}$ and $A$ are all positive constants. Show the the solutions to these ODEs can never oscillate (proof for $T_1$ is sufficient). In other words, the temperature of the caramelized sugar can only behave as overdamped response.

\begin{equation*}
T_{1}'=k_{11}(A-T_1)+k_{12}(T_2-T_1)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
T_{2}'=k_{21}(A-T_2)+k_{22}(T_1-T_2)
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite the system as

\begin{eqnarray*}
T_{1}'=k_{11}A-(k_{11}+k_{12})T_1+k_{12}T_2\\
T_{2}'=k_{21}A+k_{22}T_1-(k_{21}+k_{22})T_2
\end{eqnarray*}
and again in a matrix form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
T_1\\ T_2
\end{bmatrix}'
=
\begin{bmatrix}
k_{11}+k_{12}&k_{12}\\
k_{21}+k_{22}&k_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
T_1\\ T_2
\end{bmatrix}
+
A
\begin{bmatrix}
k_{11}\\k_{21}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The eigenvalue/eigen vectors of the matrix are
$$\lambda_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}(k_{11}+k_{12}+k_{22}\pm D)$$
and
$$v_{\pm}=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}\frac{k_{11}+k_{12}-k_{22}\pm D}{k_{21} + k_{22}}
\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
where
$D=\sqrt{(k_{11} - k_{22})^2 + 2 k_{11} k_{12} + k_{12}^2 + 4 k_{12} k_{21}  + 2 k_{12} k_{22} }$
and the solution to the homogeneous system ($A=0$) is given by $$a v_+e^{\lambda_+t} + b v_-e^{\lambda_-t} $$
which can only oscillate if $\lambda$ is complex. Since all the coefficients are positive, this can be only if $D$ is complex, i.e. its argument is negative.

Since argument of $D$ is sum of positive numbers, $D$ is real - you done.

Note, since the inhomogeneous part is constant it won't make it oscillatory.